# Databricks: How to solve DBFS DOWN?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I use Azure Databricks. In a notebook I tried to do:

```
dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/")
```

And I have this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to perform &#39;getMountFileState(forceRefresh=true)&#39; for mounts after 3 attempts. Please, retry the operation.

Original exception: 'shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
```

In Event logs in Databricks I see DBFS DOWN.

How can I solve the DBFS DOWN ?

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons for DBFS DOWN error could be that the driver node is overloaded, for example if you have many users who use the same cluster, etc.  To resolve it you may need to increase driver memory, decrease number of users in the cluster, etc.

But the real error is the `This request is not authorized to perform this operation` - usually it happens if you didn't allow access to the storage account from other networks - check the firewall rules for the storage account, and add Databricks workspace networks to allowed ranges.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try it all. I tried with a new cluster with higher memory for the driver but still have DBFS DOWN. I don't understand why I have "This request is not authorized to perform this operation" because everything worked very well few days ago.
About the firewall rules I have:  "All networks, including the internet, can access this storage account"

Comment: Storage key wasn’t rotated?

Comment: Access key is still the same. When I try dbutils.fs.mount, the error comes at "extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key."+storageName+".blob.core.windows.net": accessKey})"